# Spice simulation of a motor switching power supply

Tags: motor, voltage-regulator, pmos, switching

I'm designing a switching regulator for motor controlling, I have tried this circuit with spice but it does not work:

[image]

The problem is that the voltage on the load of the regulator never goes down, as is depicted in the picture:

[image]

Is there anyone to explain me why?

Comment: In what way does it not work? What's the failure?

Comment: @JohnHonniball edited

Comment: Which is load, can you please explain bit more.

Comment: The load is a dc motor, modeled in the picture @AKR

Answer (score 1):

You are using a model of a P-channel FET, which is hooked upside down, so body diode conducts all the time. Source needs to connect to +12V and drain needs to connect to R1 C2 node. Also, D1 is in the wrong place, anode should go to ground while cathode goes to R1 C2 node.

[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102819/micro-mosfet-and-dc-motors) is a related question concerning drive of brushed DC motors.