# Correct MOSFET choice for brushed DC motor

Tags: mosfet, motor, pwm, dc-motor, driver

I'm looking for a few MOSFETs for a really small motor. [This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/102819/micro-mosfet-and-dc-motors) is exactly what I am asking but I'm afraid this might be marked as a duplicate.

Basically, I have really small motors rated more or less 1A 3.7V. The answer provided in the question was to use a [SSM3K123TU](http://www.semicon.toshiba.co.jp/info/docget.jsp?type=datasheet&lang=en&pid=SSM3K123TU) mosfet but I'm having a hard time looking for the specific piece. What I found instead while roaming around eBay were these:

- [IRF9540 IRF9540N Power MOSFET P-Channel 23A 100V](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10Pcs-IRF9540-IRF9540N-Power-MOSFET-P-Channel-23A-100V-/321648275465?hash=item4ae3bb3009)
- [IRF3205 TO-220 IRF 3205 Power MOSFET 55V 110A](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5pcs-IRF3205-TO-220-IRF-3205-Power-MOSFET-55V-110A-/221623505619?hash=item3399ca52d3)
- [IRFZ44N IRFZ44 N-Channel 49A 55V Transistor MOSFET Component TO-220](http://www.ebay.com/itm/20PCS-IRFZ44N-IRFZ44-N-Channel-49A-55V-Transistor-MOSFET-Component-TO-220-power-/321546901171?hash=item4addb056b3)
- [IRF840N IRF840 N-channel 8A 500V MOSFET TO-220 IR Transistor](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10Pcs-IRF840N-IRF840-N-channel-8A-500V-MOSFET-TO-220-IR-Transistor-/221726659126?hash=item339ff05236)
- [2N7000 MOSFET N-CHANNEL 60 Volts 0.2 Amps TO-92](http://www.ebay.com/itm/100pcs-2N7000-MOSFET-N-CHANNEL-60-Volts-0-2-Amps-TO-92-top-/221572885276?hash=item3396c5eb1c)
- [IRF510NPBF IRF510N IRF510 Power MOSFET N-Channel 5.6A 100V](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2pcs-IRF510NPBF-IRF510N-IRF510-Power-MOSFET-N-Channel-5-6A-100V-/221729314861?hash=item33a018d82d)

I'm guessing that these are extremely overkill for my purposes, but I might be wrong. I'm just looking to control a 1A 3.7V motor using PWM. I'm concerned that these might be too inefficient and there might be smaller ones available.

Are these okay to use with a small load or should I go look for smaller ones?

---

This might/might not help:

Power source: 3.8V to 5V

Max motor current: <1.5 A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to do a direct answer: -

A good start is to look at absolute maximum voltages and current and check that any potential MOSFET you choose is ~ twice as good as what you believe you need for your circuit.

Next, I'd look at what the SSM3K123TU device does for you and this graph is very important: -

[image]

It tells you plenty of things about how good it will be at delivering power to the motor whilst not getting too warm itself. For instance, with a 1.2 volt gate-source drive and a 1A load (motor) you might expect to see an 70mV drop across the MOSFET. This is a power dissipation of 70mW. However, if your circuit could drive the gate with 4 volts, expect only a 20mV drop across the MOSFET when delivering 1A to the motor.

So that's it in simple terms - choose a MOSFET that matches what the SSM3K123TU delivers in these respects and you are likely to be able to make a long list of potential mosfets turn into a short list.

Comment: So basically, I can choose whatever mosfet I want, as long as it can accommodate my needs. Is that right or is there something horribly wrong with what I just said? @Andyaka

Comment: As an addendum to this - the first sentence of Andy's answer should help you immediately eliminate one of the MOSFETs you proposed in your initial question.

Comment: @PandaLion98 understanding your needs is the hardest part usually.

Comment: Alright, if you want to be pedantic, the first line containing technical information.